# Convert SQL to ServiceStack.ORMLite Sql Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack

How to convert the following SQL to ServiceStack.OrmLite Sql Server format?

```
/* Total Receipts */
select convert(date, t.TransactionDate) [Date], tm.TeamId,a.AccountNumber, count(distinct(t.RequisitionNumber)) Total
from task.tblTransactions t
inner join task.tblRequisitions r on r.RequisitionNumber = t.RequisitionNumber
inner join task.tblAccounts a on a.AccountNumber = r.AccountNumber
inner join Team tm on tm.DivisionId = a.DivisionId
where t.TransactionTypeNumber = 201 and a.IsActive = 1 
and t.TransactionDate between @fromDate and @toDate
group by convert(date, t.TransactionDate), tm.TeamName, a.AccountName
order by 1,2 desc
```

My Result class:

```
public class KpiTotal : IKpiTotal
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }

    public int TeamId { get; set; }
    public Team Team { get; set; }

    public int AccountId { get; set; }
    public Account Account { get; set; }

    public double Total { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For custom SQL like this, you'd use OrmLite's Custom SQL API's, with something like:

```
var results = db.Select<Poco>(@"select convert(date, t.TransactionDate) [Date], 
  tm.TeamName, a.AccountName, count(distinct(t.RequisitionNumber)) Total
  from task.tblTransactions t
  inner join task.tblRequisitions r on r.RequisitionNumber = t.RequisitionNumber
  inner join task.tblAccounts a on a.AccountNumber = r.AccountNumber
  inner join Team tm on tm.DivisionId = a.DivisionId
  where t.TransactionTypeNumber = 201 and a.IsActive = 1 
    and t.TransactionDate between @fromDate and @toDate
  group by convert(date, t.TransactionDate), tm.TeamName, a.AccountName
  order by 1,2 desc", new { fromDate = fromDate, toDate = toDate });
```

Where `fromDate` and `toDate` is your parameterized variables and `Poco` is a custom type with fields that match the returned result set.

Comment: Cool, In this case how can I LoadReferences? I added my result class @mythz

Comment: @RogerOliveira You wont be able to with Custom SQL, but you maybe able to use the new [Merge extension method](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite#merge-disconnected-poco-result-sets) to merge disconnected POCO's together based on their reference definitions.

Comment: How is the performance comparing to a simple foreach loading the references manually? @mythz

Comment: @RogerOliveira Great to hear. Merge API is pretty tight, where it avoids runtime reflection and uses compiled delegates to populate fields.